# search an item in an list and print out the list which contains that item

Tags: python, list

I'm currently writing a test code for a project which takes the ingredients in your fridge and runs it over the recipes, and prints out the recipes that have your ingredients.

### But I'm a bit frustrated because no matter how hard I try, the result wouldn't match. Here's a test run.

```
ingre = 'đùi gà, hành lá'

content = 'dvjkshdvjkdsnvjksuihv đùi gà, djghajhdjfkasjkd Hành lá'

ingres= ingre.split(',')

content_list = content.split(',')

print(ingres)

print(content)

index  = content_list.index('đùi  gà')
print('Vị  trí  của  công  thức  chứa  đùi  gà  là', index)
```

---

Even though it should print out the 'dvjkshdvjkdsnvjksuihv đùi gà', but instead the program displays

ValueError: 'đùi  gà' is not in list

Can someone help me understand why is it not working?

Comment: Your list after splitting contains `'dvjkshdvjkdsnvjksuihv đùi gà'`, not `'đùi  gà'`.

Comment: `ingres` contains `đùi gà`, not `content_list`.

Answer (score 0):

You are Finding an index of `'đùi  gà'` as an element in your content_list. but content_list contains `['dvjkshdvjkdsnvjksuihv đùi gà', ' djghajhdjfkasjkd Hành lá']` that's why it displays ValueError: 'đùi gà' is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Example among many others if you want to get the index of the ingredient if he's on the list of recipees:

```py
ingredient = "dui ga, hanh la"

ingres= ingredient.split(',')

content = 'dvjkshdvjkdsnvjksuihv dui ga,djghajhdjfkasjkd hanh la'

content_list = content.split(',')

print(ingres)
print(content_list)

searching = "dui ga"

for item in content_list:
    if searching in item:
        print("index -> ", content_list.index(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_index_of_string_from_list_of_strings(search_string, content_list):
    i = 0
    for string in content_list:
        if string.index(search_string) >= 0:
            return i
        i += 1
        return -1


                
ingre = 'đùi gà, hành lá'

content = 'dvjkshdvjkdsnvjksuihv đùi gà, djghajhdjfkasjkd Hành lá'

ingres= ingre.split(',')

content_list = content.split(',')

print(ingres)

print(content)

index = find_index_of_string_from_list_of_strings('đùi gà', content_list)

print('Vị trí của công thức chứa đùi gà là', index)
```

As you are trying to get the substring searched within content_list which is a list of strings, creating a function like this should work...